# image_tag for delete method with HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Need help  with implementing HAML image_tag into link_to with delete method:

= link_to "Remove project", @project, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Burn it to the ground" }

It took second to do the same with Edit action

```
def edit_icon
    link_to image_tag("edit.jpg", alt:"Edit", id:"edit_logo", height: "700px", width: "30px"),    edit_project_path(@project)
end
```

But with Delete I just can't figure out whats up with parentheses

Help will b appreciated

Comment: and the code you have for delete is?

Comment: Actually code for delete is what I'm asking for)

Comment: and what's wrong with that code?

Comment: In my post I have delete code without image_tag and for now it displays like a simple link. I just want to maki it a linked picture(like "delete icon")

Comment: the code you posted (and then deleted) was correct.

Comment: Yes, I know. it works 100%. I just want it to look something like:

link_to image_tag("delete.png", alt:"Remove project", @project, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Burn it to the ground" })

But that way it doesn't work

Comment: @dimitryeurope You need to differentiate between image options and link options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
= link_to image_tag('image.jpg', alt: 'Remove project'), @project, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Burn it to the ground" }
```

Comment: Usually it's better to use `button_to` for destructive actions.